# STOMP client for Chrome Apps

Tags: sockets, rabbitmq, dart, stomp

I'm trying to build a STOMP library that can be used to connect to RabbitMQ from chrome apps. My initial experiments from outside chrome worked well. However, I'm unable to convert the Socket code to work from within chrome apps. Can the client api code below be modified to work from within chrome apps?

Answer (score 1):

My initial experiments have been successful. I'd love to see a complete Socket API in the client side dart libraries so that we could use such code directly from chrome apps. While there is some effort to provide a Socket API using the js socket capability of chrome it is not as clean as the one in the dart.io package available to server side code.

Here's the code. To use it, deploy RabbitMQ and enable the STOMP plugin.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  List<String> versions = ["1.2","1.1","1.0"];
  String host = "127.0.0.1"; // localhost
  int port = 61613; // rabbitmq default port
  Socket.connect(host, 61613).then((connection) {
    String hostpath="/";
    String login = "guest"; // rabbitmq default login
    String passcode = "guest"; // rabbitmq default passcode
    stomp(connection, versions, hostpath, login, passcode); // stomp connect
    connection
      .transform(new StompTransformer())
      .listen((frame) {
          if(frame.headers.containsKey("ack")) {
            ack(connection, frame.headers["ack"]);
          }
          dumpStompFrame(frame);
          stdout.write("enter a message> ");
        },
        onDone: () { print("done"); },
        onError: (e) { print (e); } );
    subscribe(connection, "/queue/a", 1, "client", true);
    stdin
      .transform(new StringDecoder())
      .transform(new LineTransformer())
      .listen((line) {
        send(connection, "/queue/a", line);
      });
  });
}

/* 
 * STOMP
 * accept-version:1.0,1.1,2.0
 * host:/
 * 
 * ^@
 */

void stomp(Socket connection,
  List<String> versions,
  String hostpath,
  String login, String passcode) {
  connection.writeln("STOMP");
  if(versions.length > 0) {
    connection.writeln("accept-version:${versions.join(',')}");
  }
  connection.writeln("host:$hostpath");
  connection.writeln("login:$login");
  connection.writeln("passcode:$passcode");
  connection.writeln();
  connection.add([0x00]);
}

/*
 * SUBSCRIBE
 * id:0
 * destination:/queue/foo
 * ack:client
 * 
 * ^@
 */
void subscribe(Socket connection,
  String destination,
  int id, String ack, bool persistent) {
  connection.writeln("SUBSCRIBE");
  connection.writeln("id:$id");
  connection.writeln("destination:$destination");
  connection.writeln("ack:$ack");
  connection.writeln("persistent:$persistent");
  connection.writeln();
  connection.add([0x00]);
}

/*
 * UNSUBSCRIBE
 * id:0
 * 
 * ^@
*/
void unsubscribe(Socket connection, int id) {
  connection.writeln("UNSUBSCRIBE");
  connection.writeln("id:$id");
  connection.writeln();
  connection.add([0x00]);
}

/*
 * ACK
 * id:12345
 * transaction:tx1
 * 
 * ^@
*/
void ack(Socket connection, String id, [String transaction]) {
  connection.writeln("ACK");
  connection.writeln("id:$id");
  if(?transaction) {
    connection.writeln("transaction:$transaction");
  }
  connection.writeln();
  connection.add([0x00]);
}

/*
 * NACK
 * id:12345
 * transaction:tx1
 * 
 * ^@
*/
void nack(Socket connection, String id, [String transaction]) {
  connection.writeln("NACK");
  connection.writeln("id:$id");
  if(?transaction) {
    connection.writeln("transaction:$transaction");
  }
  connection.writeln();
  connection.add([0x00]);
}

/*
 * BEGIN
 * transaction:tx1
 * 
 * ^@
 */
void begin(Socket connection, String transaction) {
  connection.writeln("BEGIN");
  connection.writeln("transaction:$transaction");
  connection.writeln();
  connection.add([0x00]);
}

/*
 * COMMIT
 * transaction:tx1
 * 
 * ^@
 */
void commit(Socket connection, String transaction) {
  connection.writeln("COMMIT");
  connection.writeln("transaction:$transaction");
  connection.writeln();
  connection.add([0x00]);
}

/*
 * ABORT
 * transaction:tx1
 * 
 * ^@
 */
void abort(Socket connection, String transaction) {
  connection.writeln("ABORT");
  connection.writeln("transaction:$transaction");
  connection.writeln();
  connection.add([0x00]);
}

/*
 * SEND
 * destination:/queue/a
 * content-type:text/plain
 * 
 * hello queue a
 * ^@
 */
void send(Socket connection, String queue, String message) {
  connection.writeln("SEND");
  connection.writeln("destination:$queue");
  connection.writeln("content-type:text/plain");
  connection.writeln();
  connection.write(message);
  connection.add([0x00]);
}

class StompServerFrame {
  String frame;
  Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
  List<int> body = new List<int>();
  String toString() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.writeln(frame);
    for(String key in headers.keys) {
      sb.writeln("$key=${headers[key]}");
    }
    sb.writeln(new String.fromCharCodes(body));
    return sb.toString();
  }
}

void dumpStompFrame(StompServerFrame frame) {
  print("BEGIN STOMP FRAME DUMP");
  print(frame.toString());
  print("END STOMP FRAME DUMP");
}

class StompTransformer extends StreamEventTransformer<List<int>, StompServerFrame> {
  List<String> serverFrames = ['CONNECTED', 'MESSAGE', 'RECEIPT', 'ERROR'];
  String state = 'COMMAND'; // 'COMMAND', 'HEADERS', 'BODY'
  List<int> token = new List<int>();
  StompServerFrame stompServerFrame = new StompServerFrame();
  StompTransformer() {}
  int lastValue = -1;
  void handleData(List<int> intList, EventSink<StompServerFrame> sink) {
    for(int b in intList) {
      switch(state) {
        case 'COMMAND':
          if(b == 0x0a) { // done with command
            stompServerFrame.frame = new String.fromCharCodes(token);
            state = 'HEADERS';
            token.clear();
          } else {
            token.add(b);
          }
          lastValue = b;
          break;
        case 'HEADERS':
          if(b == 0x0a && lastValue == 0x0a) { // done with all headers
            state = 'BODY';
            token.clear();
            lastValue = -1;
          } else if(b == 0x0a && lastValue != 0x0a) { // done with a header
            String tokenString = new String.fromCharCodes(token);
            List<String> tokenStringParts = tokenString.split(":");
            if(tokenStringParts.length == 2) {
              stompServerFrame.headers.putIfAbsent(tokenStringParts.elementAt(0),
                  () => tokenStringParts.elementAt(1));
            } else {
              // possible header format error
              print("was here with $tokenString");
            }
            token.clear();
            lastValue = b;
          } else {
            token.add(b);
            lastValue = b;
          }
          break;
        case 'BODY':
          if(b == 0x00) { // done with body
            sink.add(stompServerFrame);
            stompServerFrame = new StompServerFrame();
            state = 'COMMAND';
            token.clear();
            lastValue = -1;
          } else {
            stompServerFrame.body.add(b);
          }
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```